# Transferring file audio/text over bluetooth in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

i am trying to send any text or image/audio file over bluetooth using RFCOM server socket.i used the following code

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkBTPermissions();

               // byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
               // mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
               file_permission();

               // byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                File myfile = new File("/sdcard/bluetooth/tom.txt");
                byte[] bytes= new byte[(int)myfile.length()];

                Log.d(TAG,"file length() =" + (int)myfile.length());
                try {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myfile);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis,(int)myfile.length());

                    //bis.read(bytes,0,bytes.length);

                    Log.d(TAG,"fis created");
                    // FileInputStream
                    mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
```

here i am able to send the contents of my text file and even able to receive.
receiver code:

```
public void run(){
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream                 
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()   
            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                // Read from the InputStream
                try {

                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer); 
                    String incomingMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "InputStream: " + incomingMessage);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "write: Error reading Input Stream. " + e.getMessage() );
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

My question how i can send my file as a whole to the receiver and receive it and save it ?.Among various tutorials i only find how to send text over bluetooth. please help.

Comment: `here i am able to send the contents of my text file and even able to receive` ??? if you are able to send a file then i do not understand what you are asking. `My question how i can send my file as a whole to the receiver` It looks as if you are already doing that. (In a bad way ... but that is a different story.).

Comment: @greenapps i make a text file locally then on the receiver end i only receive the contents of the file.if this is the case then do i have to create a text file again at receiver and then write the  data into it ?

Comment: Yes indeed. That should all be done.

Comment: @greenapps Really this is how data is transferred in Bluetooth,as i thought i will be getting the file as it is ?. if i send a audio/image/pdf,again  i have to create at the file at the receiver ?

Comment: If you send a file then you send a number of bytes. No more . No less. The receiver can do with the bytes as it wishes. If it thinks its a file the bytes should be save to disk. Pretty normal. Sending code and receiving code are the same for every type of file. As you just send and receive some bytes.